# Set-theoretic difference of two languages in CFL - REG

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

Let $L_1,L_2\in$ CFL $-$ REG, with $L_1\subset L_2$. Which of the following always holds?

1. $L_1-L_2\in$ CFL $-$ REG and $L_1-L_2\in$ REG.
2. $L_1-L_2\in$ REG and $L_2-L_1\in$ CFL $-$ REG.
3. $L_1-L_2\in$ REG. $L_2-L_1\in$ REG.
4. $L_1-L_2\in$ REG. As to $L_2-L_1$, it may be in REG or not.
5. None of the above.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: First statement states that L1, L2 are context free languages which are not regular and L1 is a subset (a part) of L2. L1 - L2 will then be null. L2 - L1 will be those strings which are in L2 but not in L1. Answer according to me should be (b)

Comment: I thought it might be non of the above

Comment: @kiner_shah I understand what you're saying and it seems reasonable

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: What is the connection between the picture presented and *intersection of languages*?

Answer (score 0):

Since $L_1-L_2=\emptyset\in$ REG, we only need to consider $L_2-L_1$.

Consider $L_1=\{a^nb^n\mid n\text{ is a positive integer}\}, L_2=\{a^nb^n\mid n\text{ is a non-negative integer}\}$, then $L_2-L_1=\{\epsilon\}\in$ REG.

Consider $L_1=\{a^nb^n\mid n\text{ is a positive odd integer}\}, L_2=\{a^nb^n\mid n\text{ is a positive integer}\}$, then $L_2-L_1=\{a^nb^n\mid n\text{ is a positive even integer}\}\in$ CFL $-$ REG.

Hence, the correct answer is 4.